# Converting Json to data class inside sealed class in Kotlin

Tags: json, kotlin, gson, moshi

I have this API Response

```
{
  "id": 45,
  "name": "Bill",
  "status": "Alive",
}
```

the `status` prop can have three possible results: `Alive`, `Dead` and `Unknown`. I would like to convert the `status` prop to a sealed class, so I can use relatable props to the status, like the status color. I'm looking for somethhing like this:

```
sealed class Status(val color: Color) {
    object Alive : Status(Color.Green)
    object Dead : Status(Color.Red)
    object Unknown : Status(Color.Gray)
}
```

I know that there's some libs that can help me, like Gson or moshi, but im struggling to find something to help me.

Comment: This should just be an enum class for simplicity. Then I think those libraries could do it automatically.

Comment: I would make a serializable class for the id, name, status structure... Then write code to convert from that class to the expected output.

Comment: You can do this with Moshi. Check out this polymorphism adapter: https://github.com/square/moshi/blob/master/moshi-adapters/src/main/java/com/squareup/moshi/adapters/PolymorphicJsonAdapterFactory.kt